# Function imposed on a list

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to write a Haskell function that takes makes use of this function:

> E(x,y)(i,j) = ((i*i) - (j*j) + x, (2*i*j) + y)

The list `F(x,y)` of a point `(x,y)` should be an infinite list of items:

> F(x,y) = {(0,0) , F(x,y)(0,0), F(x,y)(F(x,y)(0,0)), F(x,y)(F(x,y)(F(x,y)(0,0))), and so forth}

From my understanding, the nth entry of a list `F(x,y)` is the `E(x,y)` function composed with itself n times and then applied to `(0,0)`

This is what I'm thinking so far:

```
entry :: (Int,Int) -> [(Int,Int)]
efunction (i,j)(x,y) =  ((i*i) - (j*j) + x, (2*i*j) + y)
entry (x,y) = efunction(0,0)(x,y) where
    efunction = (0,0) : iterate efunction(i,j)
```

Also, `(x,y)=(0,0)` and remains static. The only variables that change are `(i,j)`.

A sample output would be

```
entry(1,1) = 
0,0
1,1
1,3
-7,7
1,-97
```

I'm pretty new to Haskell so I'm been trying to wrap my head around why this doesn't work and how to actually make it work. Any help?

Comment: On a side note, Haskell supports complex numbers out of the box, via the [Data.Complex](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Complex.html) module.

Comment: The only reason I see that your code doesn't work is that you have efunction declared right between entry's type declaration and definition.  Just move efunction above entry, below entry, or into a where clause inside entry.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're on a good way, using `iterate` is the right thing. You have a function of two arguments, and want to iterate it with one of the arguments fixed. It's more convenient to use in `iterate` if the fixed argument is the first, so let's define

```
step (x,y) (i,j) = (i*i - j*j + x, 2*i*j + y)
```

Then you get your desired list by iterating the partially applied function `step (x,y)` with an initial point of `(0,0)`,

```
entry (x,y) = iterate (step (x,y)) (0,0)
```

It may be more easy to follow if you define a local function using the argument of `entry` instead of the partially applied `step`,

```
entry (x,y) = iterate next (0,0)
  where
    next (u,v) = (u*u - v*v + x, 2*u*v + y)
```

Have fun producing your Mandelbrot set ;)